# For comprehension that has to handle 2 optional values and return a Option[T]

Tags: scala, scala-cats, cats-effect, doobie

The below code works fine, but as you can see the 2nd clause in the `for comprehension` has a call that is unsafe.

```
case class ProductView(product: Product, stores: List[Store], warehosue: Option[Warehosue])

def loadView(...): ConnectionIO[Option[ProductView]] = 
for {
   product <- getProductById(id)  // ConnectionIO[Option[Product]]
   warehouse <- getWarehouse(product.get.warehouseId.get.id) // ConnectionIO[Option[Warehouse]]
   stores <- loadStores(...)     // ConnectionIO[List[Store]]
} yield product map { p =>
    ProductView(p, stores, warehouse)   
}
```

I tried to make that a safe call, but my types don't seem to line up.

```
   warehouse <- getWarehouse(product.get.warehouseId.get.id)
```

How can I improve this, if any of the options is a `None`, I just want to return a `None`.
This is suppose to return a `Option[Warehouse]`

I tried this:

```
warehouse <- product.map(p => p.warehouseId.map(id => getWarehouse(id)))
```

Hoping someone can help with this part of my for comprehension.

Comment: Maybe `OptionT` or `mapN`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez thanks, can you help with wrapping each line?  Should I use `OptionT.liftF` for the ConnectionIO[List[T]] statements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is using `OptionT` and `flatTraverse`

```scala
def loadView(id: Int):
  ConnectionIO[Option[ProductView]] =
    (for {
      product <- OptionT(getProductById(id))
      warehouse <- OptionT.liftF(product.warehouseId.flatTraverse(getWarehouse))
      stores <- OptionT.liftF(loadStores(...))
    } yield ProductView(product, stores, warehouse)).value
```

Also alternative variant without `OptionT`

```scala
  def loadView(id: Int): ConnectionIO[Option[ProductView]] = {
    getProductById(id).flatMap {
      _.traverse { product =>
        for {
          warehouse <- product.warehouseId.flatTraverse(getWarehouse)
          stores <- loadStores(...)
        } yield ProductView(product, stores, warehouse)
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: It seems the entire thing returns a `None` if the call to ```warehouse <- OptionT(product.warehouseId.traverse(getWarehouse))``` returns a None... I want it to still return with just a `None` for warehouse.

Comment: You are right. I updated my example. Then you can use liftF if you don't react on this Option.

Comment: Also I added a variant without OptionT